# restore nuget package conflict

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

In VS2019, in the Package Manager Console, I start to update all packages of my solution with `update-package`, but it stops at;

> update-package : Unable to find package
> 'System.Management.Automation_PowerShell_3.0'. Existing packages must
> be restored before performing an install or update. At line:1 char:1
>
> - update-package
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand

So I right click on my solution and ask to restore nuget packages but then, I have a contradictory piece of information.

> All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
> Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0759442
> ========== Finished ==========

When I manage solution nuget packages (right click on solution, `manage nuget packages for solution`), in the updates tabitem, I select all packages and ask for update, I have a:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which is not related to my code (build succeeds).

How to proceed ?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing all of the nuget packages? Open the CLI and run `Update-Package -reinstall`

Comment: Did you use [packages.config nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) or [packagereference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files)?

Comment: Actually, `System.Management.Automation_PowerShell_3.0` nuget package does not exists on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/). Is the nuget package your own package? And this leads the error that you cannot find the package. You should config the nuget package path on the [nuget package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources) and it can also be the local path. Also, check the path and then try again.

Comment: Could you please share your `packages.config` file with us? Actually, when you click `restore nuget packages` by the button and works well(all nuget packages of your solution exists), there is no reason why this `update-package` command does not works.

Comment: Hi Soleil, any update about this issue? Please feel free to let us know if it works or not to help us support further.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thanks for your great post, but I managed to resolve the issue before I came back on SO to read your solution. Unfortunately I did not write down what I did exactly. At some point I deleted Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions, ...Caching.Abstractions and ... Logging.Abstractions with which I was having also issues, and then updated all the other packages one by one.  I'm having a shared project used by .net core 3.1 and .net4.8. I had also issues with mixted AnyCPU and x64 projects and nuget packages looking for x86 versions. In a way I crafted my way through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite strange about this behavior, actually, when you click `restore nuget packages` by the button and works well which proves that all nuget packages of your solution exists), there is no reason why `update-package` command does not works.

So please try the following suggestions to troubleshoot the issue:

**Suggestions**

**1)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders)

**2)** check your [nuget package sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources). check those sources which your nuget packages are installed from and uncheck those sources which you are not used.

Remember to check the private nuget source of `System.Management.Automation_PowerShell_3.0`.

**3)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of your project.

delete all vs component caches under `C:\xxx(current user)\perryq\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache`

**4)** try to use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)(a default vs environment without any your third party vs installed extensions or packages) to start your Vs and then test your project.

====================================================================

**5)** Try to create a new project and then install  `System.Management.Automation_PowerShell_3.0` and several nuget packages and then test it.

**If** it does not exist on the new project, I think there may be some conflicting versions of nuget packages in your original project. You should check your installed packages carefully or you could share the `packages.config` file with us to troubleshoot the issue.

**6)** first make a backup of your [nuget package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources). Then, close VS, delete the global `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`.

**Then** restart your VS, and then readd the required nuget package sources into VS to test your project.

**7)** [Repair your VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or if your VS2019 is not the latest, please update it which might have a fix about it.